# C# .NET equivalent of Java Swing Actions

Tags: c#, java, .net, swing, user-interface

Whilst programming Java GUis I made heavy use of the [Action](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) class.  The instantiated action class was passed to numerous button or menu item constructors so that you only had to code the logic in one place.

Each time you clicked on a button/icon/menuitem associated with the action the actionPerformed method would fire and execute the code.

This was a great time saver and allowed me to write the logic only once.

Questions:

1. Is there a similar class in C# or .NET framework?
2. Have I got this all wrong and there is a different way to have one set of logic called from multiple buttons/icons/menuitems?

Comment: Events. It's all about the Events. Instead of passing in a class to handle everything, each Event is wired separately. One can create a single object with the handlers and wire all the events to that object to get "the Java way" -- I tried this once, but it doesn't fit well in C#/WinForms. The same delegate can be wired to multiple events, of course.

Comment: I've not used them before, but the C# [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=VS.100).aspx) comes to mind (as far as passing one as a parameter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.Net uses events heavily and you can do something like this if you have common functionality.

```
protected void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Common code here
   // You can use sender parameter to distinguish b/w the buttons.
}
```

and

```
button1.Click += button_click; 
button2.Click += button_click; 
button3.Click += button_click;
```

Answer (score 0):

C# usually uses events to associate behavior with user actions. You can use a single event handler to handle the click on several buttons or menu items.

BTW, C# is a language, not a GUI framework. There are several GUI frameworks that you can use with C# (Windows Forms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET), and each one is different. So your question isn't really related to C#, but rather to one of these frameworks.